# Keras Sequence, fit_generator and steps_per_epoch

Tags: python, keras

I've noticed that with `fit_generator`, the `steps_per_epoch` parameter is usually assigned `total_samples//batch_size`, where one can create a generator/use `ImageDataGenerator` and pass it as an argument to `fit_generator`.

However I am using the `Sequence` class (`keras.utils.Sequence()`) to create my generator and passing `steps_per_epoch` an integer less than `total_samples//batch_size`.

What I would like to know is would the generation of data start in the generator start from the beginning once each epoch is completed?

For example, I have 3200 samples in my training set and I use a batch size of 32. So ideally for one complete epoch I should set `steps_per_epoch` to 100. However what would happen if I set my `steps_per_epoch` to 50? Once the first epoch is completed would data point number 1601 (32*50) be generated or would it start from the beginning (data point number 1) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using `Sequence`, you do not need to pass `steps_per_epoch`, as this information can be inferred from the `__len__` method of your `Sequence.`

If you pass `steps_per_epoch` while using `Sequence`, this will override any use of the `__len__` method and it will effectively only use `steps_per_epoch` samples from your sequence (from 0 to `steps_per_epoch - 1`), and it will reset back to zero at the end of the epoch. You can check this behavior in the [keras source code](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/engine/training_generator.py#L178).

Comment: Is there any workaround to this? I would like data to be generated infinitely and model evaluation for checkpoints only to run every `steps_per_epoch`.

Comment: @JashShah Workaround to what? That is how it works by default, you just need to make sure that your Sequence generates data infinitely

Comment: Workaround for the generator to not reset back to zero after every `steps_per_epoch`

Comment: @JashShah the sequence index is an abstraction, you can just return different images in each epoch, there is no need for any workaround.

Comment: I did not understand this. Can you please elaborate further? How can I return different images in each epoch?

Comment: @JashShah I cannot really elaborate further, there is no context like source code, you just make a generator or Sequence that returns different images at each epoch, in a generator/Sequence you have complete control on what is returned to Keras.